# avoiding loop inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know if there is any way to avoid loops inside loops, for example:

```
let underscore = require('underscore');

_.each(obj, (val, key) => {
  _.each(key, (val, key) => {
    _.each(key, (val, key) => {
       // Finally i have access to the value that i need
    });
  });
});
```

I'm working with a complex MAP object, which have maps and arrays deep inside. Obvious i can't replace the loops.. but i would like to know if i can change my code to make it more clear.

Thanks.

Comment: yes, there are ways.

Comment: @squint technically speaking you've answered the question...

Comment: @squint, there are *other* ways too

Comment: @kapetanios, that's a vicious rumor!

Comment: @kapetanios: Hell, there even are *better* ways…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can break your code up in a much cleaner way than you have here to avoid nested loops. Lets say you had a structure like this:

```
// lets invent some hash of people, where each person
// has an array of friends which are also objects
var people = {
    david: { friends: [{name:'mary'}, {name:'bob'}, {name:'joe'}] },
    mary: { friends: [{name:'bob'}, {name:'joe'}] }
};

function eatFriendBecauseImAZombie(myName, friendName) {
    console.log(myName + ' just ate ' + friendName + '!!');
}

// (inner loop 2) how to parse a friend
function parseFriend(myName, friend) {
    eatFriendBecauseImAZombie(myName, friend.name);
}

// (inner loop 1) how to parse a person
function parsePerson(name, info) {
  _.each(info.friends, (val) => parseFriend(name, val));
}

// (outer loop) loop over people
_.each(people, (val, key) => parsePerson(key, val));
```

output is:

```
david just ate mary!!
david just ate bob!!
david just ate joe!!
mary just ate bob!!
mary just ate joe!!
```